# Label tag value is not displaying in the form

Tags: html, css, angular, forms, bulma

I have to the get the name of the ingredient and price of that using the form. But in that form i set the label tags to display the label of the input field it is not displaying in the front-end.

> Here i am using angular and bulma css.

**It is the my component.html page.**

```
<div class="columns">
<form>
    <div class="field column is-horizontal">
        <div class="field column is-two-thirds">
            <label class="label" for="name">Name</label>
            <div class="control">
                <input class="input is-medium" type="text" placeholder="Ingrediant name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field column is-two-fifths">
            <label class="label" for="amount">Amount</label>
            <div class="control">
                <input class="input is-medium" type="number" placeholder="price">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**In front-end showing like this. And i attached inspect element in the console part also :**
[image]

[image]

*How to get back the label element to display*
*Thanks in advance*

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried putting an id on your input elements ?

> To associate the label with an input element, you need to give the input an id attribute. The label then needs a for attribute whose value is the same as the input's id.

[label documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Label)

Comment: @tomsarray Thanks . Today i learnt about label tag detailed from this command.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.
I got a solution from myself. I just removed ***class="label"*** from the `<label>` tag. It is the **bulma** css class for label. As of now the label tag and the input field is.

> ```
> <label for="name">Name</label>
> <div class="control">
>     <input class="input is-medium" type="text" placeholder="Ingrediantname">
> </div>
> ```

```
 <div class="columns">
    <form>
        <div class="field column is-horizontal">
            <div class="field column is-two-thirds">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="input is-medium" type="text" placeholder="Ingrediant name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field column is-two-fifths">
                <label for="amount">Amount</label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input class="input is-medium" type="number" placeholder="price">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>`
```